What if negative is less conductive than positive wire in DC circuit?
In almost all trucks, the chassis and battery's negative are shorted. Say we are to install a vehicle tracker that operates on 12v DC. The positive sides are connected via a copper wire but the negative sides are connected via the chassis, which is made of mild steel.
It is known that mild steel has less conductivity than copper. Will the tracker experience a voltage drop because of high resistivity of mild steel compared to copper? Will fast flow of electrons in copper wire and slow return of electrons in mild steel causes any issues?

Tip: The term neutral usually refers to the common in an AC system. For DC use "negative", "common" or "ground" depending on the configuration and context.

"Shorted" might not be the right word to use here. Normally a "short circuit" is a fault condition. A "short" usually is a low-resistance electrical connection between two points that are not supposed to be connected. An electrician might say that the chassis is bonded to the negative terminal of the battery. I'm not sure what an automotive mechanic would say about it. "Grounded?" maybe?

Compare the cross-section of the copper wire to the cross-section of the mild steel chassis. Now, remembering that total resistance is inversely proportional to cross-section area, which path do you think likely has a lower overall resistance (even though copper has lower resistivity than steel)?

The resistance of the wire and the resistance of the chassis both cause a voltage drop due to the load current.
Typically the load can't tell the difference and only sees the total drop.
Certainly the speed of the electrons in the conductor (it's very slow for any typical currents) is only of interest from a physics point-of-view, and is unseen by the load.

But will not the total drop increases in this case as the drop because of chassis is greater, compared to a scenario where both positive and common is copper or same material.

@AwaisSaeed no, the only thing that matters is the total resistance around the circuit.

@AwaisSaeed the conductivity (conductance per amount of material) is higher, but the body is a lot bigger than the wire, isn't it? so it conducts better?

Using the vehicle chassis as the battery-negative return conductor is common practice. Saves weight, space, and fuel.
The resistance of a conductor is determined by its material, length, and cross-sectional area. So, while copper wire presents a low resistance because it is made of copper, it does not have a lot of cross-sectional area. OTOH, steel has much lower conductivity than copper, but the chassis has a massive cross-sectional area, thus giving it lower resistance than copper wire.
So, you will incur some voltage drop on the copper wire and chassis but within specification. 12-volt gizmos, gadgets, and toys should be made to work for the entire range of a vehicle battery system from 10.5 to 14.4 volts.
Your assumption is incorrect; the chassis conductor has lower resistance than your copper wire. Limit your voltage loss on the positive wire to .2 volts, and you will be in good shape. To answer your question directly, the conductor with the highest resistance will incur the highest voltage drop. In your application, that will be the copper wire. As long as the total voltage drop is within specification, 3% is considered a low voltage drop for mission-critical equipment and 5% for lighting and non-critical loads.

Re, "steel has much higher conductivity" Did you accidentally type the wrong word there?

The electrons do not flow at different speeds. You have just basically two wires with two different materials and two different sizes. So that can't cause any issues.
There will be a voltage drop through both routes, which does depend on material and gauge of wiring and all contact resistances.
Now, what can cause issues is that if all the loads use the same return path, which is the chassis, then the voltage drop depends on all the other currents as well. In a car radio you might hear it as a buzz that depends on the RPM. A GPS tracker likely does not care as it has good filtering and DC converters in it.

If electrons flow in both materials with same speed, then will it be true that the chassis is dissipating more energy and the rest of the electrons are returning with same speed? I am confusing conductivity (which is how well electrons are allowed to flow) of the two different materials.

@AwaisSaeed In electronics you don't work with electrons so forget about moving electrons. Most of the time it is enough to work with resistances,  currents and voltages.

Several other answers and comments here talk about which part of the circuit actually has more resistance than which other part. But, that's missing the point. It does not matter where the resistance in the circuit is located.
As a very rough analogy, you can think of the electrons delivering power from the battery to, say, the headlights in a similar way to how the links in a bicycle's drive chain deliver power from the cranks to the rear wheel. If you "resist" the motion of the chain anywhere, then the whole chain slows down. It doesn't make sense for one part of the chain to move faster than another part. That's not how chains work.
That's not how electric current works either. Current flows in loops (e.g., from the battery, through the "positive/supply" wire, through the headlights, through a "negative/ground" wire or through the chassis, and back to the battery.)
If you have a single loop (no branch points*) then no matter how many different resistances the current encounters in the loop, no matter where they appear, if you measure the current anywhere in the loop, you'll get the same value as if you measure it anywhere else.

*If you have several components (e.g., two or more light bulbs) connected in parallel, then the current leaving the battery branches. At each branch point, some of the current goes one way, and the rest of the current goes other ways. The bicycle-chain analogy completely fails to model circuits with parallel branches. It only works for a single loop.

"if you measure the current anywhere in the loop, you'll get the same value as if you measure it anywhere else." - So, if you have five bulbs in parallel each dissipating 12W at 12V, you mean current consumption will be same at every point? Doesn't seem right. As you move from bulb A to B, you'll read 1A less. Your explanation holds true if bulbs are in series. The issue is that in a car,  most devices are rather connected in parallel, so the farther away the device is, the more voltage drop it sees across it's inputs compared to devices that are physically closer to the battery.

@15Volts, You are correct. I have edited my answer to make it clear that I was talking about current flowing in a single loop, with no parallel branches.
